# startActivity overridePendingTransition only shows enter animation

Tags: android, android-intent

Basically, the issue I'm experiencing is that only the enter slide animation is showing; the calling Activity doesn't animate.

```
    startActivity(intent);
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.right_in_partly, R.anim.left_out_partly);
```

I know for a fact it's not the animation file, as replacing the exitAnimation (the second argument in the method call) with the one that works still has no effect and does not animate at all.

Strangely enough, the reverse is seen when calling finish() from the second Activity.

```
    finish();
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.left_in_partly, R.anim.right_out_partly);
```

When that is called, the exit animation for the second Activity shows, but the first Activity still does not animate.

Again, replacing the enterAnimation (first argument) with one that we know works (exitAnimation) still has no effect, so it is definitely not the animation file.

Anyone have any ideas as why this would happen? I'm stumped...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you been able to solve it?

Comment: The issue stopped occurring, and I'm not sure, but I think it was solved by adding a ZAdjustment to the Animation set: <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
      android:zAdjustment="top">

Comment: I had that same problem and the zAdjustment worked fine! If you post it as response I´ll vote it up

Comment: Going to make it an answer then since it's helped several of us

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since no one has been able to give us a reason as to why this is occurring, here's how I got around it by adding a ZAdjustment to the AnimationSet:

```
<set xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"; 
     android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator" 
     android:zAdjustment="top">
```

For some reason that allowed the exit animation to work.

Comment: you are a lifesaver

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem by making the below changes

`<item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">false</item>`