# Dialog windowEnterAnimation does not work on a specific Activity only

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment, android-dialog

> ```
> <style name="DialogSheetAnimations">
>     <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/slide_in_bottom</item>
>     <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/slide_out_bottom</item>
> </style>
> ```

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity(), R.style.DialogSheetAnimations);
```

This works on some activity, but it does not work on one specific Activity

On Activity A **windowEnterAnimation and windowExitAnimation works**
on Activity B ***windowEnterAnimation does not work*** but **windowExitAnimation works**

Any idea why is this happening?

Comment: What's the diff between two activitys?

Comment: I had a similar problem a long time ago, and solved it by adding a zAdjustment to the animation. Checkout this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16365187/startactivity-overridependingtransition-only-shows-enter-animation

Comment: I have the exact same problem. Seriously what the heck is going on.